How do I know that my saddle fits me
I have recently bought one of these fancy 3d printed saddles (fitzik vento argo adaptive r3, 140mm). However, I don't know whether it truly fits me. I do road rides and always with bib shorts. The saddle feels fine, very comfortable, but after some 2 hours of riding, I start to feel my bum. Mostly some pressure points in the seat bone area. Is this normal or do I need another saddle?

Does this question have an answer to your question?  - https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/6323/how-long-does-it-take-to-get-used-to-a-hard-saddle

Remember its a saddle, not a seat.  You can transfer weight from your backside onto the pedals, which helps you go faster too.

Assuming the rest of your bike fit is correct, I think you can be reasonably sure a saddle fits you if you basically don't really notice it after a long ride outdoors. That is, it shouldn't hurt you.
If your bike fit is off, then my understanding (not a fitter, but I listen to some podcasts from bike fitters) is that that can cause you to sit on your saddle in such a way that causes discomfort. For example, if your saddle is a bit too high, our bodies instinctively tend to compensate to one side (on average, you try to protect your dominant side). That might cause unilateral saddle discomfort. Let that go too long and you would also expect to see unilateral joint pain.
Unfortunately, because it takes a while on the saddle to know, it's often hard to find a good saddle. Few saddles have return programs. Fizik does, but Colby Pearce (Cycling in Aligment podcast) criticized their overall fit philosophy, and he especially criticized the Arione. Fortunately, that's for performance roadies and not many people ride it.
My understanding is that a lot of people report that the Specialized Power saddles work well. Interestingly, that includes the Power Mimic (targeted at women) working for a lot of men. I don't know who else makes saddles that work well enough for a lot of people. Specialized also doesn't have a saddle trial program. Bontrager/Trek will take returns for any reason within 30 days. I'm not sure how well their saddles are regarded.

IIRC the specialized power started off as a women's saddle, but male testers ended up really liking it too, and so it was marketed as unisex.

"I think you can be reasonably sure a saddle fits you if you basically don't really notice it after a long ride outdoors" where "long" is personal to the rider.  While I can know a saddle is atrocious within minutes (more of that spent adjusting than riding), the boundary between OK and good takes a ride of a couple of hundred km to test - but that's because that's the distance I'm used to.


The saddle feels fine, very comfortable, but after some 2 hours of riding, I start to feel my bum. Mostly some pressure points in the seat bone area. Is this normal or do I need another saddle?

Normal if you have had a break from active riding, not normal if you have ridden  actively for a month.
Saddles tend to be noticed mostly after a break from riding, such as a winter break. Many expensive saddles have been sold in vain by bike shops for the reason that someone has had a long break from cycling, then notices the saddle hurts, then buys the most expensive saddle available to think it solves all problems. It doesn't, it hurts too, but the rider has spent so much money that he's unwilling to admit the expensive saddle won't work. Until, after the rider has used the new saddle for a month, it doesn't hurt anymore. Then the rider thinks it must be the expensive saddle that has some magical feature that makes it good. Not so. Even the old saddle would have stopped hurting after a month of riding.
Try doing 2 hours of riding every day for a month. If the saddle still hurts, then you have something wrong with your bike fit. Maybe it's the saddle, maybe it's of incorrect width for example for your anatomy. Or maybe something else is off in the bike fit, causing you to have too much pressure on the saddle and too little on the pedals and handlebars.
Also, if you aren't athletic, then month of riding won't fix all your problems. For example one month is not a long enough interval to lose lot of overweight for example. The month of riding is enough for those who are athletic but just had a break from cycling.
My experience with saddles is that basically anything is fine as long as it's the correct width (most are). However, my sit bone width is typical, for those with atypical sit bone width, finding good saddles can be harder.
